# android:layout_centerHorizontal not working

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/firstview"
            android:src="@drawable/paint_shop"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           />
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstview">
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CHHABRA ASSOCIATES"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFE033"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FF3333"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here `android:layout_centerHorizontal` is not working properly. what is the reason??I have added relative layout viewgroup over text view but it is not working. I want to center the text

Comment: how the view should look, the image on top and text below it, or how?

Comment: image below and text on top  and text should be in center

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/firstview"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_check_circle"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstview">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CHHABRA ASSOCIATES"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#FFE033"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FF3333"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```